# Is it possible to include a file with a form POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I got a regular POST in my mvc app:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "AController", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div style="margin-bottom:20px"></div>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-input">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="@(nameof(Model.Name))" value="@(Model.Name)" />
        </div>
        <br />

        <div class="form-input">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="@(nameof(Model.Name2))" value="@(Model.Name2)" />
        </div>
        <br />

        <div>
            <input type="file" name="Image" id="Image" name="@(nameof(Model.Image))" value="@(Model.Image)" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">TEXT HERE</button>
    }
```

Now when doing the submit the two regular text fields gets binded the model but the file does not.
After some reading it seems like the upload part should be in a separate form, **is that correct**?

I really want to avoid having two different `POST` as it does not fit the design of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the posted file from the Request directly in the controller with following code

```
if(Request.Files.Count > 0)
{
    var file = Request.Files[0];
    ...
}
```

But you need to add the multipart/form-data to your form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "AController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data" }))
```

Check [What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) for reference on the multipart/form-data